# Unable to see colored cells in Pandas data-frame in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pycharm

I am using PyCharm tool for Python coding. I have framed a data-frame using pandas. I have provided conditional font color formatting in the python code. But, in the output dataframe, I am not able to see the expected colors. Is it a problem with PyCharm or with my code ?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(5, 4)), columns=list("ABCD"))
print(df)
def color_positive_green(val):
    color = 'red' if val < 0 else 'green'
    return 'color: %s' % color
df.style.applymap(color_positive_green)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine. If you use `render()` or `to_html()` methods, you can check the output:

```
>>> df.style.applymap(color_positive_green).to_html()

<style type="text/css">
#T_3ad17_row0_col0, #T_3ad17_row0_col1, #T_3ad17_row0_col2, #T_3ad17_row0_col3, #T_3ad17_row1_col0, #T_3ad17_row1_col1, #T_3ad17_row1_col2, #T_3ad17_row1_col3, #T_3ad17_row2_col0, #T_3ad17_row2_col1, #T_3ad17_row2_col2, #T_3ad17_row2_col3, #T_3ad17_row3_col0, #T_3ad17_row3_col1, #T_3ad17_row3_col2, #T_3ad17_row3_col3, #T_3ad17_row4_col0, #T_3ad17_row4_col1, #T_3ad17_row4_col2, #T_3ad17_row4_col3 {
  color: green;
}
</style>
<table id="T_3ad17">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="blank level0" >&nbsp;</th>
      <th id="T_3ad17_level0_col0" class="col_heading level0 col0" >A</th>
      <th id="T_3ad17_level0_col1" class="col_heading level0 col1" >B</th>
      <th id="T_3ad17_level0_col2" class="col_heading level0 col2" >C</th>
      <th id="T_3ad17_level0_col3" class="col_heading level0 col3" >D</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th id="T_3ad17_level0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0" >0</th>
      <td id="T_3ad17_row0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >73</td>
      <td id="T_3ad17_row0_col1" class="data row0 col1" >44</td>
      <td id="T_3ad17_row0_col2" class="data row0 col2" >75</td>
      <td id="T_3ad17_row0_col3" class="data row0 col3" >73</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="T_3ad17_level0_row1" class="row_heading level0 row1" >1</th>
      <td id="T_3ad17_row1_col0" class="data row1 col0" >50</td>
      <td id="T_3ad17_row1_col1" class="data row1 col1" >13</td>
      <td id="T_3ad17_row1_col2" class="data row1 col2" >43</td>
      <td id="T_3ad17_row1_col3" class="data row1 col3" >86</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="T_3ad17_level0_row2" class="row_heading level0 row2" >2</th>
      <td id="T_3ad17_row2_col0" class="data row2 col0" >81</td>
      <td id="T_3ad17_row2_col1" class="data row2 col1" >16</td>
      <td id="T_3ad17_row2_col2" class="data row2 col2" >3</td>
      <td id="T_3ad17_row2_col3" class="data row2 col3" >87</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="T_3ad17_level0_row3" class="row_heading level0 row3" >3</th>
      <td id="T_3ad17_row3_col0" class="data row3 col0" >13</td>
      <td id="T_3ad17_row3_col1" class="data row3 col1" >26</td>
      <td id="T_3ad17_row3_col2" class="data row3 col2" >23</td>
      <td id="T_3ad17_row3_col3" class="data row3 col3" >67</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="T_3ad17_level0_row4" class="row_heading level0 row4" >4</th>
      <td id="T_3ad17_row4_col0" class="data row4 col0" >29</td>
      <td id="T_3ad17_row4_col1" class="data row4 col1" >20</td>
      <td id="T_3ad17_row4_col2" class="data row4 col2" >34</td>
      <td id="T_3ad17_row4_col3" class="data row4 col3" >37</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see your code works:

[image]

In PyCharm, it's not possible to view the render in the console, you have to enable the [Scientific Mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-tutorial.html) and check the SciView.